# How to make both infowindow and setzoom working for Google map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I should start with saying I do not understand much about javascript or Google API V3. Anyway, I have been trying to include a google map with markers to indicate places where I have visited with infowindow. I found an example on internet which I copied to my page. I then tried to add a function to zoom in to the place when clicking the marker. I managed to get the zooming working really nice after changing the code. However, the infowindow will not open. Before it was open when I used this;

```
infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
infowindow.open(map,marker);.
```

But the zooming did not work properly. After changing to this;

```
infowindow.setContent(this.html);
infowindow.open(map, this);
```

the zooming worked nice. But I lost the infowindow. Can anyone see how I can change the code to make both zooming and infowindow working. I would be very happy if anyone could assist me with this. Can I use the code below with adjustments, or is a complete rewrite needed? THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
// this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the    side_bar 
var side_bar_html = "";

// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;

function initialize() {
    // create the map
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.516231, 13.550072),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    // Add markers to the map
    // add the points 

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(48.208174, 16.373819);
    var marker = createMarker(point, "Vienna", '<div style="font-size:12px;font-weight:   bold;font-family:segoe ui, Trebuchet MS;">Vienna</div>')

    // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 100)
});

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        map.setZoom(10);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    // add a line to the side_bar html
    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length - 1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you change it from `(map, marker)` to `(map, this)`? Think you should just use marker.

Comment: @putvande - why do you think that? He should actually use `this`

Comment: A : by `map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); map.setZoom(10);` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you changed the code to use a .html property of a marker (google.maps.Marker objects don't have a .html properties, but you can add them).

2 options for fixing it:

- Use your original code:

  ```
  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
  function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
      var contentString = html;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
          map.setZoom(10);
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });

     // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
     gmarkers.push(marker);
     // add a line to the side_bar html
     side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length - 1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
  }
  ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_infowindowAndZoom.html)

- Add .html to the google.maps.Marker and use `this`:

  ```
  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
  function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          html: html,  // <---------------------------------------------- add this to the Marker
          zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infowindow.setContent(this.html); 
          infowindow.open(map,this);
          map.setZoom(10);
          map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
     });

     // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
     gmarkers.push(marker);
     // add a line to the side_bar html
     side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length - 1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

By default the API will pan the map so that the infowindow will be completely visible(if possible).

This will be done by using an animation, this animation is still running when you set zoom+center and will override your settings.

set the **`disableAutoPan`**-option of `infowindow` to **`true`** to disable the automatic panning and it should work as expected

Comment: Coming home from work, seeing the replies to my question made me excited :) THANKS!! I honestly thought I would make this working now. BUT, after trying proposals from "davidkonrad" and "Dr. Molle", I still don't get the infowindow to open. To answer "putvande"; Yes, the zoom + infowindow worked (almost). The problem was often it did not zoom in to the position of the clicked marker, but another location, far from the marker position